# Flutter web must I http to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, http, web

Good day.  I am new to flutter web.  If someone can assist or point me where I can get the correct info I would appreciate it.  I need to save data in mysql on the same server that the flutter web app is uploaded to.  What I want to know is if I must do a http request even though the mysql and webapp is on the same server?  I guess I need to create a .php file to post and fetch data from the mysql database.  But if you are on the same server do you http to the .php or is there another way?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use this package (haven't tried it myself):

https://pub.dev/packages/mysql_client

Create connection pool

```
final pool = MySQLConnectionPool(
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    userName: 'your_user',
    password: 'your_password',
    maxConnections: 10,
    databaseName: 'your_database_name', // optional,
);
```

Or single connection

```
final conn = await MySQLConnection.createConnection(
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 3306,
    userName: "your_user",
    password: "your_password",
    databaseName: "your_database_name", // optional
);

// actually connect to database
await conn.connect();
```

Query database

```
var result = await pool.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM book WHERE id = :id",
    {"id": 1},
);
```

Results:

```
for (final row in result.rows) {
    print(row.assoc());
    row.colAt(0); // returns first column as String
    row.typedColAt<int>(0); // returns first column as int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant with "`HTTP to MySQL`", to directly from Front-end access `MySQL` through some Web-API, then no there is no such thing supported by MySQL.

**But** you can create your own Web-API Back-end (a `.php` script), which redirects requests to `MySQL`, and then Front-end only needs to communicate with said Back-end.

The Front-end may seem to be on same server,
but the Front-end logic runs on the user's Browser, which is far away from server.

Comment: Thank you for that.  Now understand a bit better.  So even though the web page and mysql is on same server the data is recieved from the browser and thus I have to do http or https request to the .php to insert or retrieve the data from the mysql.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Hendrik if this was helpful, consider accepting and/or up-voting (there should be a tick-mark button and/or up-arrow button somewhere above).